# Transpose data in Mysql

Tags: mysql, transpose

suppose I have the following data, how can I transpose the data with MYSQL so that the output looks like the following table?

```
WITH mydata
AS (SELECT '123' AS id,
1   AS he_has_logo,
0   AS i_have_logo,
1   AS he_has_image,
1   AS i_have_image)
SELECT *
FROM   mydata


variable    he  i
has_logo    1   1
has_image   1   0
```

Comment: What if you have more than 1 row in the table being transposed?

Comment: Why isn't the `id` in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION`

```
SELECT 'has_logo' AS variable, he_has_logo AS he, i_have_logo AS i
FROM mydata
UNION ALL
SELECT 'has_image' AS variable, he_has_image AS he, i_have_image AS i
FROM mydata
```